# Semidirect product of metaplectic group and Heisenberg group

Tags: automorphic-forms, theta-functions, heisenberg-groups

I know that Symplectic group has an action on Heisenberg group.

I am wondering how to extend this to non-trivial two fold metaplectic covering?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Well, trivially, by projecting to the symplectic group …?  Do you have some other action in mind?  If so, why?  Do you know that it exists, or just hope?  Also, over what field?

Comment: @LSpice, Oh, the action uses the projection map from the metaplectic group to symplectic group. Since many people use the semi-direct product of metaplectic group and Heisenberg group, I just wondered people’s convention. Thank you!

Comment: Why close this beautiful question with even more beautiful answer?

Comment: @BugsBunny Because there was no effort from OP (even after LSpice's comment) to be more precise, e.g., symplectic group over which field, in what dimension, Heisenberg group in which sense?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I presume you are looking for a faithful action of $Mp_{2n}$ on something related to the Heisenberg group $H_{2n+1}$. This is well-known as Weil Representation.

In the modern language, consider $Mp_{2n}$ acting on $H_{2n+1}$ by automorphisms. This action has a kernel. Now consider the action on the category of unitary representations of $H_{2n+1}$ by twisting representations by automorphisms. This categorical representation still has the same kernel. Finally, choose a skeleton of the category of unitary representations of $H_{2n+1}$. The modern interpretation of all this Weil and Stone–von-Neumann business is that $Mp_{2n}$ acts on the skeleton and this yields a faithful categorical representation of $Mp_{2n}$.

Comment: Thank you very much!  I learned much from your comments!